# Grouping arguments in tidyverse: Bin by consecutive number of levels in a variable with missing levels

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with monthly data `month` on herbivore parasitism  `result` for various types of parasitoid order 'psitorder' with levels "Hymenoptera" or "Diptera". The result is either "p" for parasitized herbivore, "a" if the herbivore grew to adult, or there is no data "" because the herbivore died in captivity.

```
 df<-data.frame(month= c(rep(1, each=8), rep(2, each=6), 
                    rep(3, each=6), rep(4, each=8), 
                    rep(5,each=6),rep(6, each=6), 
                    rep(8,each=6),rep(9, each=6)),
                result= c(rep("p",each=3),rep("a",each=3), 
                     rep("",each=2),rep("p",each=3),rep("a",each=2), 
                     rep("",each=1),rep("a",each=3),rep("",each=3),
                     rep("p",each=3),rep("a",each=3),rep("",each=2),
                     rep("p",each=3),rep("a",each=2), 
                     rep("",each=1),rep("a",each=3),rep("",each=3),
                     rep("p",each=3),rep("a",each=3),rep("",each=2),         
                     rep("a",each=4)),
                 psitorder=c(rep("Hymenoptera",each=2),
                     rep("Diptera",each=1),rep("",each=5),
                     rep("Hymenoptera",each=1),rep("Diptera",each=3),
                     rep("",each=2),rep("",each=6),
                     rep("Hymenoptera",each=2),rep("Diptera",each=1),
                     rep("",each=5),rep("Hymenoptera",each=1),
                     rep("Diptera",each=3),rep("",each=2),
                     rep("",each=6),rep("Hymenoptera",each=2), 
                     rep("Diptera",each=1),rep("",each=9)))
```

I would like to group by the `month` variable, however, I need to group by every 3 consecutive months of data. Here, in this example, `month` 1,2,3 would be grouped and months 4,5,6, and for month 7,9 I would need to add the missing month 8 so that consecutive rows continue to be used to calculate `psit_freq`.

Once grouped, I want to calculate `psit_freq` using the method below.

I have tried:

```
output %>% 
group_by(month+3) %>% 
mutate(complete(continuous_month= seq(min(continuous_month), 
max(continuous_month), 1L))%>%
summarise(hym_freq = sum(psitorder == 'Hymenoptera')/sum(result %in% c('p', 'a')), 
          dip_freq = sum(psitorder == 'Diptera')/sum(result %in% c('p', 'a')))
```

The output would look like:

```
output<- data.frame(group= c("1", "2", "3"), hym_psit= c(3/14, 
         3/14,2/10), dip_psit= c(4/14,4/14,1/10))
```

Answer (score 0):

We create a grouping variable with `%/%`

```
data_frame(month = 1:9) %>% 
       full_join(., df) %>% 
       group_by(group = (month-1)%/%3 + 1) %>%
      summarise(hym_freq = sum(psitorder == 'Hymenoptera', na.rm = TRUE)/sum(result %in% c('p', 'a'), na.rm = TRUE), 
           dip_freq = sum(psitorder == 'Diptera', na.rm =TRUE)/sum(result %in% c('p', 'a'), na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   group  hym_freq  dip_freq    
#    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1 0.2142857 0.2857143
#2     2 0.2142857 0.2857143
#3     3 0.2000000 0.1000000
```